# How does power get to the flywheel in a motorized gyroscope?

Tags: gyroscope

When I look at my toy gyroscope (I have never seen the inside of a motorized gyroscope), the central flywheel is suspended within the various gymbals and needs a lot of freedom of movement.  It's hard to see how an electric motor in the flywheel hub could be supplied with power.

How do "real" gyroscopes maintain angular velocity in their flywheel?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since there is no information about the specific gyro, you are talking about, one can think of providing power through some kind of [slip rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_ring) or simpier [brush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brush_(electric)) contacts.

Comment: Upvoted, but I still would love to see a detailed answer involving (any) specific gyro.

Comment: So maybe you should specify it?The gyro you have, I mean.

Comment: I don't have one, I'm really just curious!  So a peek into any actual gyro would do.